# jQuery Iteration with WordPress Feed

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, loops

I'm building a work portfolio using a WordPress category feed and jQuery to show some effects when you hover over a portfolio example. I would like to iterate using jQuery and a WordPress feed so the effect works for each of my portfolio examples... I have successfully done this for the first example in my portfolio, however getting it to work on each portfolio example is proving challenging. I understand each portfolio example needs a unique identifier but I don't understand how to apply it to each one. Please see the code below thank you for helping me

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.recentWork').hover(function(){
     $(".links").stop(1).slideDown();
         $(".imagio").fadeOut();
  },function(){
     $(".links").stop(1).slideUp();
         $(".imagio").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php

    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)){
        $thumbsrc = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'medium');
    }else{
        $thumbsrc = "<img src=\"images/no_featured_image.jpg\" style=\"width:100%;height:180px;\">";
    }

    $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, "URL", true);
    $website = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Website", true);      

    ?>

    <div class="recentWork">

        <div class="links">
        <a href="<?php echo $website; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/images/icons/icon_zoom.png" /></a><a href="<?php echo $website; ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/images/icons/icon_more.png" /></a><br />
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="imagio">
        <?php echo $thumbsrc; ?>
        </div>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses class selectors

```
$('.className')
```

or node selectors

```
$('div')
```

or both

```
$('div.className')
```

Then inside of your hover handler, use

$(this)

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.recentWork').hover( 
    function(){ 
      $(this).find('.imagio').fadeOut(); 
      $(this).find('.showLinks').fadeIn(); 
    }, 
    function(){ 
      $(this).find('.imagio').fadeIn(); 
      $(this).find('.showLinks').fadeOut(); 
    } 
  );
});
```

Comment: I've been trying to take what you said and apply it... changed the elements to classes but still having some trouble following. Do you mind applying your example code to my code? I get that I would want to add a class to links to display them but I don't see how based on the structure of my code..

Comment: $(this) refers to the current selector which in the code example above is $('div.recentWork') from there you want to find the div.links inside of the recentWork block?  I am assuming that you have several div.recentWork blocks on your page?  Not sure which parts are repeating.  If you post the html with the multiple blocks I could help with selectors more.  I'm just guessing since I don't know how your php is going to render.

Comment: think I got it now...

    $('div.recentWork').hover(
    function(){
    $(this).find('.imagio').fadeOut();
    $(this).find('.showLinks').fadeIn();
    },
    function(){
    $(this).find('.imagio').fadeIn();
    $(this).find('.showLinks').fadeOut();
    }
    );